# Programming language or library with UltraEdit macro-like text parsing capabilities

Tags: parsing, text, macros

UltraEdit has a very powerful built-in macro engine. With commands like "Find", "Replace", "Select", and "Delete", and regular expressions, it makes writing automatic text parsing and modifying tools a breeze. To demonstrate what I mean, I wrote an entire script converter from a Lua-like language to a C-style language with UE's macro engine and it was very easy. Doing the same in a low-level language like C++ would've been practically painful in comparison.

I was wondering if there are any scripting or programming languages (or libraries for languages like C++ that matter) with similar capabilities? I would just use UltraEdit, but I need to simultaneously parse several thousand pages and put their data in an SQL database, so I need a bit more power than UltraEdit can give me to do it efficiently. A C or C++-like language would be preferable.

Comment: I don't understand the question (I never heard of UltraEdit). Emacs' Elisp is also a power tool for text processing. OcamlDuce, Perl, Python, CommonLisp, Ocaml, Haskell, XSLT, Snobol, .. also. And there are many libraries or tools (ANTLR...) to help parsing.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Basile that Emacs Lisp might be a good choice.  Emacs also has such a keyboard macro system (probably much more sophisticated than UltraEdit), and this system can translate macros back to lisp code so that you can load them back any time.

Have a look at [the Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html#Keyboard-Macros), especially section [Basic Keyboard Macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Basic-Keyboard-Macro.html#Basic-Keyboard-Macro) and section [Save Keyboard Macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Save-Keyboard-Macro.html#Save-Keyboard-Macro).

Answer (score 0):

[Perl](http://www.Perl.org) is pretty highly regarded as language in which to do rather arbitrary string hacking on big documents.